# Validate Wikipedia formula for Wishart conditioned on a conjugate prior

Tags: st.statistics

In the Wikipedia entry for "[Inverse-Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution)" ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inverse-Wishart_distribution&oldid=889156164)) there is a formula for a Wishart distribution conditioned on a conjugate prior ( $\Psi,\nu$) in which the original Wishart scale matrix $\Sigma$ has been integrated out to  yield the conditional distribution

$$ p(X\mid\Psi,\nu) = \frac { |\Psi|^{\nu/2}\Gamma_p( \frac {\nu + n}{2})}{\pi^{np/2}
|\Psi+X^TX|^{(\nu+n)/2} \Gamma_p (\frac{\nu}{2})}  $$
where $A_{n\times n} $ is the observed data $X^TX $.

This doesn't appear to be a valid Wishart distribution - which I think should be something more like  
$$ p(X) = \frac { |\Psi|^{\nu/2}\Gamma_p( \frac {\nu + n}{2})}{\pi^{np/2}
|\Psi+A|^{(\nu+n)/2} \Gamma_p (\frac{\nu}{2})} \exp \Big [-\operatorname{tr} \Big ((\Psi +\Sigma)^{-1}A \Big) \Big].$$ 
So am I misunderstanding this and the formula is a partial result for illustration purposes only?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution shown is not a Wishart distribution, it is a multivariate t-distribution. This is the marginal distribution of $X$ after integrating the covariance matrix out of the Gaussian sampling model. The expression may not be correct (I haven't checked carefully, but it doesn't look quite right). A good reference for the derivation is section 1.4.3 of the book Markov Chain Monte Carlo: Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference by Gamerman and Lopes.

Comment: The equation also differs from Wikipedia's own definition of a multivariate t distribution so it needs to be clarified. My problem is in comms and has known zero means everywhere: only the covariance part is of interest.  I had referred to Murphy's "Conjugate Bayesian analysis of the Gaussian distribution" previously.

Comment: The density given appears to have a typo (not clear if it intends to integrate over the prior or the posterior), but it is closer than it looks after applying the matrix determinant lemma to $|A + \Psi|$, to get $(1 + X^t \Psi^{-1} X)|\Psi|$, which is the more familiar t-distribution form.